# Update value with two values combination

Tags: mysql

i have a table, with the columns
id, name, cv. Example,

```
id   name   cv
1    Jon    CV.pdf
```

i want to update CV.pdf with value of `name-CV.pdf`
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple update query, please use search button.

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET cv = concat(yourtable.name, '-', yourtable.cv)
WHERE cv = 'CV.pdf'
```

Comment: you are missing the name part of the question OP wants Jon-CV.pdf as a result and not -cv.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to update all values of cv? If so,

```
UPDATE table1 
SET cv = CONCAT(name, '-', cv)
```

if you only want to update the values which are 'CV.pdf':

```
UPDATE table1 
SET cv = CONCAT(name, '-', cv) 
WHERE cv = 'CV.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update MY_TABLE
set cv = CONCAT(name, '-', cv)
where id = 1
```

Comment: you are missing the name part of the question OP wants Jon-CV.pdf as a result and not -cv.pdf

Comment: Right... Didn't understand well the question.